# Where/How do I define variables in data for Vue Js methods?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm learning Vue Js and have created a simple button counter and in my methods object I created a click function to increment my counter variable.
I added counter to data but it keeps telling me counter isn't defined in count().

```
<template>
   <div class="button-container">
      <button class="counter-button" v-on:click="count">Click Me</button>
      <p>Button has been clicked {{ counter }} times</p>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: 'AnotherComponent',
      data: function() {
         return {
            counter: 0
         }
      },
      methods: {
         count: function() {
            counter++;
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is looking for a local variable called `counter`, but you never defined that.

Instead, you have to reference the *instance* property using `this.counter`:

```
 count: function() {
    this.counter++;
 }
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Handling-User-Input for a complete example.